# Unable to interpret memory_profiler results of a Tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-profiling

I have been getting output from memory_profiler similar to those from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588889/interpreting-memory-profiling-results-in-python) question. The script in question is a simple Tensorflow loop to train a neural network. I am unsure what the negative values under the "Increment" column should mean in the context of memory use, especially since they don't seem to be accompanied by changes in the total memory use ("Mem usage").

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   176    423.5 MiB    423.5 MiB   @profile()
   177                             def learning_fcn():
   178                                 global errors
   179                                 global rg_out
   180                                 global yhat
   181   8742.0 MiB -11505.6 MiB       for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
   182   8742.0 MiB -931882.3 MiB           for start, end in zip(range(0, len(trainx_rg), MINI_BATCH_SIZE), range(MINI_BATCH_SIZE, len(trainx_rg), MINI_BATCH_SIZE)):
   183   8742.0 MiB -920308.5 MiB               sess.run([train_op_mse, extra_update_ops], feed_dict={X_1D_init: np.sort(trainx_rg[start:end]), X_2D_init: np.sort(np.reshape(trainx_rg[start:end], (MBS_DIM, MBS_DIM))), _t: 1.0,
   184   8742.0 MiB -920457.2 MiB                                   _K: Kparam})
   185   8742.0 MiB -11747.2 MiB           mse = sess.run(tf.nn.l2_loss(yhat - rg_out), feed_dict={X_1D_init: np.sort(validx_rg[test_num * MINI_BATCH_SIZE: (test_num + 1) * MINI_BATCH_SIZE]), \
   186   8742.0 MiB  -3089.1 MiB                              X_2D_init: np.reshape(validx_rg[test_num * MINI_BATCH_SIZE: (test_num + 1) * MINI_BATCH_SIZE],(MBS_DIM, MBS_DIM)), _t: 1.0, _K: Kparam})
   187   8742.0 MiB -11505.5 MiB           errors.append(mse)
   188   8742.0 MiB -11505.0 MiB           if i % 100 == 0: print "epoch %d, validation MSE %g" % (i, mse)
   189   8726.2 MiB    -15.8 MiB       return yhat
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!